# Word meant to describe a crime where women beat men

Tags: nouns, offensive-language, pejorative-language

Word meant to describe a crime where women beat men and men often do not report it. Supposedly , the most unreported crime there is. This was famous term used around the time of Lorena Bobbitt's adventure.

Comment: Um there is a word I really do not remember the term and I have looked everywhere to find it.

Comment: So how do you know there is such a word? Somebody told you?

Comment: Yep heard this word from two completely different sources back in the 90's but cannot remember or find this word.

Comment: Although it is true that men often do not report domestic abuse, I have my doubts about it being the *most* unreported crime.  The word for which you are looking may be *misandry,* which, although it has nothing to do with criminal justice, is the counterpart to *misogyny.*

Comment: Assault (such as a slap to the face or a kick to the shins, or worse) is a typically a crime, and seldom reported. Verbal abuse is less likely to be a crime.

Comment: If you haven't heard it for 20 years and can't remember it, it's probly not used much any more, if it ever was. So if you found it and used it now nobody would understand it anyway. And, who knows? The source might have been wrong; not everything you hear is true, as it turns out.

Comment: @user1198289 Is "aggravated battery" the term you're looking for? http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/aggravated_battery

Comment: Alright alright calm down John. I do not know what in your past is causing you to attack me but misandry is plausible for what I am looking for.

Comment: [You must mean this one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment15959_4732).

Comment: Yes tchrist the unbearable data overload of a "Stack" site to which it was to suggest that any bit of the language was to be discussed is such a burden. This overloading suggest we should just give up on the P# interactions that this universe has assembled. Thus destroying all "Stacks" exchanges do to their futile attempt to satisfy the P#.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany A slap on the face or any unwanted touching is legally considered battery, not assault. http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/assault_and_battery

Comment: @Elian That's a U.S. legal definition. In Canada (and some other places) assault is the actual act as well as threatening. See S. 265 in the Criminal Code: http://www.canlii.org/en/ca/laws/stat/rsc-1985-c-c-46/latest/rsc-1985-c-c-46.html

Comment: Male domestic violence

Answer (score 4):

Women can be violent, and they can be aggressive towards their own sex, and to their own *flesh and blood*, which includes their children (of all ages); parents; and siblings.

When the victim is the spouse, partner, or boyfriend then the crime is the same as that of man using violence against his wife, partner or girlfriend; *domestic abuse*; *[domestic violence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_violence)*; or *intimate partner violence* (IPV) which also refers to gay and lesbian couples.  The victim, if male, may be referred to as a [**battered man**](http://www.webmd.com/balance/features/help-for-battered-men).

> "Domestic violence is not about size, gender, or strength," says Jan
>   Brown, executive director and founder of the **Domestic Abuse Helpline
>   for Men**. "It's about abuse, control, and power, and getting out of
>   dangerous situations and getting help, whether you are a woman being
>   abused, or a man."

Wikipedia states

> **Both women and men have been killed as the result of domestic
>   violence,** but the rate is generally lower for men. For instance, in
>   the United Kingdom, 37 percent of murdered women were killed by the
>   intimate partner and for men, 6 percent were killed by an intimate
>   partner. From 40 to 70 percent of the women murdered in Canada,
>   Australia, South Africa, Israel and the United States were killed by
>   an intimate partner. The World Health Organization (WHO) states
>   that globally, about 38% of murders of women are committed by an
>   intimate partner

**Domestic violence against men** [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_violence_against_men)

> refers to abuse against men or boys in an intimate relationship such
>   as marriage, cohabitation, dating, or within a family. As with
>   violence against women, the practice is often regarded as a crime but
>   pressures against reporting complicate issues. Laws vary greatly
>   from place to place.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I think I am looking for misandry, but this is would touch the "legal" allusion I instilled in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @user1198289 - misandry only implies dislike for women, and says nothing about beating them. Plus, of course, it says nothing about the sex of the person who show misandric, just as men can be misanthropic.

Comment: Nonono, @WhatRoughBeast. Misandry is the hatred and dislike of **men**. *Misogyny* is the hatred and dislike of women. And the adjective forms are misandristic and misogynistic.

Comment: Ack! You're right, of course. Cursed dyslexic fingers. But you got what I meant.

Comment: Yes, this. A woman could be a domestic abuser without being a misandrist, or she could be a misandrist without being violent against anyone. If you're looking for a word for the crime, it's domestic violence or IPV.  (IPV includes non-cohabitating couples; domestic violence includes non-couple members of a household.)

Answer (score 2):

Legally speaking, a case of physical violence from one person against another -- **whatever the gender** -- is considered *battery*.

> A [battery](http://www.willamadden.net/JohnLeeEsq/AboutDV/DVDefined.htm) is a hostile unwanted touching. Angrily yanking a person's shirt is a battery the same as a slap or punch. Throwing something at a person and missing, or making threatening movements, is an assault. A slap in the face is battery. Add a small scratch or bruise, a bloody nose, and the offense is more serious and might constitute in some jurisdictions an [aggravated battery](http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/aggravated_battery).

And so, the term *unreported battery* might fit what you're looking for.